# Finding upper bounds on probability that a sum of random variables exceeds some value

Tags: probability, random-variables

Suppose you had random variables $X_1, X_2...X_n$ that are iid and uniformly distributed on $[-1,1]$. I am trying to find an upper bound on the probability that the sum $S_n = X_1 + X_2 … + X_n$ exceeds some value. By Chebyshev's inequality,

$P(|S_n| \geq n\sigma_{S_n}) < 1/n^2$

However, I am interested in $P(S_n \geq value)$, not $P(|S_n|\geq value)$. Expanding the previous expression doesn't allow me to clearly separate out $P(S_n\geq value)$:

$P(|S_n| \geq value) = P(S_n \geq value)+P(S_n\leq -value) $

Is there something obvious to do next that I am missing?

Comment: There is a one-tailed version of Chebyshev's inequality $P(|X -\mu| \geq n\sigma) < 1/(1+n^2)$ but in this case it will be far from the actual value

Comment: Use Chernoff or Hoeffding here, they will be tighter than Chebyshev. And things are symmetric, so $\mathbb{P}\{ S_n \geq x\} = \mathbb{P}\{ S_n \leq -x\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Chernoff or Hoeffding here, they will be tighter than Chebyshev. And things are symmetric, so $\mathbb{P}\{ S_n \geq x\} = \mathbb{P}\{ S_n \leq -x\}$:
$$
\forall x\in [0,1], \qquad \mathbb{P}\{ S_n \geq x\} = \frac{1}{2}\mathbb{P}\{ \lvert S_n\rvert \geq x\}
$$

Comment: That's what I'm missing. Thank you! You're right, Chernoff is better.

Comment: @Sam You're welcome!